# Best way to pass environmnet vars to docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I search for way to pass envoriment variables to docker.
Most answer on stack overflow say to use the **-e** option 
This to me sounds like problem. because when you have many vars, it looks ugly. Also it shows when executing it and doing **ps** .

How to avoid it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to pass the environment variables to `docker run` command.

1. `-e` => If you want to pass the environment variable in the command-line itself. E.g.

```
docker run --env foo=bar --env foo1=bar1 alpine env
```

2. `--env-file` => Which is your case, in which you you can have a file which contains all the environment variables. E.g.:-

```
$ cat envfile
# This is a comment
foo=bar
foo1=bar1

docker run --env-file envfile alpine env
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--env-file` flag and pass file with your environment variables.

You can read more [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use docker-compose and set your environment variables inside the docker-compose.yaml file.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/